# MySQL - Ubuntu- MySQL InnoDB Cluster service (or) daemon name

Tags: mysql, service, cluster-computing, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

MySQL - In Ubuntu OS, What is the service (or) daemon name which is used by the MySQL Innodb Cluster to replicate the Data?

Comment: What version are you running?  What do you mean by "to replicate the Data"?

Comment: Ubuntu Version : 14.04.5 LTS
MySQL Versin   : 5.7.20
MySQL Innodb Cluster Note : MySQL InnoDB cluster provides a complete high availability solution for MySQL. MySQL Shell includes AdminAPI which enables you to easily configure and administer a group of at least three MySQL server instances to function as an InnoDB cluster. Each MySQL server instance runs MySQL Group Replication, which provides the mechanism to replicate data within InnoDB clusters, with built-in failover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service or daemon used by MySQL InnoDB Cluster to replicate the data. Replication is done by MySQL Server itself.

MySQL InnoDB Cluster relies on MySQL Group Replication to provide the mechanism to replicate data within InnoDB clusters.

Group Replication is a plugin for the standard MySQL Server. The plugin provides virtually synchronous replication, with built-in conflict detection/handling and consistency guarantees. It enables multi-primary (master) setups but by default, it operates in single-primary mode.

Please check the InnoDB Cluster [userguide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-userguide.html) for more information.